# Show single posts date, in a page of posts

Tags: wp-query, query-posts, meta-query, date

In a page of posts, how do I show their date, instead of the page date?
I have no php knowledge.

Let's say I want to show the single posts date here, instead to the single posts title.

```
<?php if($block === 'title'): ?>
<h2 class="post-title">
    <?php 
    echo 
        empty($link_setting) 
        || $link_setting != 'no_link' 
            ? $this->getLinked( $post, $post->title, $link_setting, 'link_title' ) 
            : $post->title 
    ?>
</h2>
```

How can I do that?

Comment: is your code within the loop?

Comment: _"I have no php knowledge."_ is a little bit of a problem. The answers here will contain PHP that you will need to understand. The site is called WordPress _developers_ for a reason. If you can't understand it, then you should get/pay yourself a developer to assist you in understanding a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`get_the_date()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_date) if you want to change the [date format](http://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time).

```
get_the_date( 'S F Y', $post );
```

The 2nd argument is optional and only needed outside the loop.

Comment: The second argument for [`get_the_date()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_the_date/) is either a post ID or a complete `WP_Post` object. Just the title won't work.

Comment: Indeed I thought his `$post` was a [WP Post object](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post), but you're right it doesn't seem so, as in this case title would be retrieved using `$post->post_title` instead of `$post->title`. We need to more code - whether it is in the loop or how/what $post is defined/contains.

Comment: I'd just assume that `$post` is an `instanceof` a `WP_Post` object. What I meant is that you can just throw `$post` as 2nd argument to `get_the_date()`. Hint: You might want to stay away from intense usage of bold formatting. This usually holds people away from upvoting.

Comment: Thanks for making the answer clearer. However you've lost me with the comments. I now better understand what you meant in the first part of the first comment, but don't get the part mentionning the title. Moreover, I'm not very familiar with OOP, and I don't understand why `$post` could be an instance of a WP_Post object and at the same time have a different name for the same variable – i.e. using only `$post->title` when according to the [WP_Post class docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post) I would have expected `$post->post_title` ? Would you mind to explain?

Comment: `WP_Post` is a class. And when you have an `object`, then you have an instance of a class. `$post = new WP_Post( .. arguments );`. So if you receive an `object` like `$post`, then you can check `if ( $post instanceof WP_Post )` and if that is true, then this `$post` object was constructed using the `WP_Post` class. The `get_the_date()` function expects as second argument a full object that is an instance of `WP_Post` and not just a property of that class (like `post_title`) is. Sidenote: A "property" is a variable _inside_ a class/object. Read more about that on php.net. Takes ~2h :)

Comment: Thanks! I'm not very clear with the "property" part and will read more on it. A last thing – for this particular case, is it correct to say that if `$post` is indeed an instance of `WP_Post`, some of its default class properties – such as `post_title` have been renamed (or others have been added?) in this way `$post->title = $post->post_title;` ?

Comment: John, just join us in [chat] tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what kind of plugin you're using there, but my guess would be:

```
<?php if($block === 'title'): ?>
<h2 class="post-title">
    <?php echo empty($link_setting) || $link_setting!='no_link' ? $this->getLinked($post, $post->date, $link_setting, 'link_title') : $post->date ?>
</h2>
```